# Updating specific record in inner collection with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

With MongoDB, if I define a collection that contains an array of dictionary values, essentially a collection within a collection, is it possible to fetch and update a specific record of the inner collection?

For example:

```
user {
   'name': unicode,
   'game_list: [ {'game_name': unicode, level: int, 'rank': int} ]
}
```

In this example, is it possible, using Python PyMongo, to fetch and update the game record from the game list for a user with name X and game_name Y? So if this user has played 10 games, I would not want to fetch and update the entire game_list but only a single game record.

Comment: But be sure that positional operator would not work for nested level more than one, i.e. array within array

Answer (score 3):

In mongodb you can update the element of an inner collection using the *positional operator*

```
db.user.update({ name : "foo", "game_list.game_name" : "bar" }, { $set : { "game_list.$.level" : 99 }})
```

see: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/